# Maintain error information with custom error pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I am trying to catch 404 and 500 errors.  I have read through so many stack over flow questions and answers that all seem to say their way is the best.  So I have just chosen one and went with it.  It does what I need it to do, however I cannot seem to get the actual error information anywhere.

I need to begin to log these to our database, how on earth do I get the error?  I want to know the link they tried to visit etc.

Here is how I filter out errors we are using IIS7+

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/PageNotFound" />
      <remove statusCode="500" />
      <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/Error500" />
    </httpErrors>
```

When I step through my PageNotFound action I can't seem to get error information.

I have tried `(Exception exception)` as a paramater, I have tried `Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();`

How do I grab the error so I can then log it to our database?

Comment: Have you looked at ELMAH for capturing errors?

Comment: Just briefly, was hoping there was a better solution than adding another third party tool. @Tommy

Comment: This error handling is done via IIS, not MVC, that's why you're not getting the exceptions. As one of the solutions you can override OnApllicationError method in your global.asax file to see the actual exceptions, or implement custom error handler global filter

Comment: What version of asp.net MVC are you using?

Comment: asp.net mvc 4.5 @ataravati

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin I added code to the global.asax file and im now able to see the error and get the information I need.  This was a pain!  But thank you.

Comment: Anyway I suggest you looking at ELMAH as it really a great tool for monitoring your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom `HandleErrorAttribute` like this:

```
public class CustomHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        // Execute the normal exception handling routine...
        base.OnException(filterContext);            

        var exception = filterContext.Exception;
        if (exception is HttpException)
        {
            var httpException = exception as HttpException; 
            if(httpException.ErrorCode == 404)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { 
                    action = "PageNotFound", 
                    controller = "Error",
                    error = httpException.Message
                }));                
            }
            // else if...
        }
    }
}
```

And, in your `FilterConfig` class under `App_Start`:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new CustomHandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```